# How do I create another csv file from yelp_academic_dataset_business.json that include only business of Hotels, Restaurant, or both?

Tags: python, dataset, data-cleaning

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7CQa.png)How do I create another csv file from yelp_academic_dataset_business.json that include only business of Hotels, Restaurant, or both categories?

The original yelp business dataset contains rows that have only Dentists, Hair Salons, etc. I want to select business of hotels, restaurants, and both only.

I just started learning python and is following a tutorial of a machine learning experiment. The below code is giving me an error. I have googled and read a lot but still don't understand. 
Any help will be appreciated.

[Image of what the yelp_academic_dataset_business.csv look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7CQa.png)

[image of code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXoWT.png)

```
data2 = []
with open('yelp_academic_dataset_business.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data2.append(json.loads(line))
len(data2)

business_id = []
city = []
state = []
stars = []
review_count = []
categories = []
postal_code = []
latitude = []
longitude = []
pricerange = []
is_open = []
name = []


for entry in range(0, len(data2)): 
    if "Restaurants" in data2[entry]["categories"]:
        business_id.append(data2[entry]['business_id'])
        name.append(data2[entry]['name'])
        city.append(data2[entry]['city'])
        state.append(data2[entry]['state'])
        stars.append(data2[entry]['stars'])
        postal_code.append(data2[entry]['postal_code'])
        review_count.append(data2[entry]['review_count'])
        categories.append(data2[entry]['categories'])
        latitude.append(data2[entry]['latitude'])
        longitude.append(data2[entry]['longitude'])
        is_open.append(data2[entry]['is_open'])
        if 'RestaurantsPriceRange2'in data2[entry]['attributes']:
            pricerange.append(data2[entry]['attributes']['RestaurantsPriceRange2'])
        else:
            pricerange.append(0)

data2 = {'business_id ':business_id,'name':name,'city':city,'state':state,'stars':stars,'review_count':review_count,
    'categories':categories,'latitude':latitude,'longitude':longitude,'is_open':is_open,'pricerange':pricerange,'postal_code':postal_code}
```

business_data  = pd.DataFrame(data2)

Comment: If including an image of text, please also [post it as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Thank you. I just figured it out how to attach code.

Comment: Can you add the file yelp_academic_dataset_business.json? or at least and example of how the json structure is?

Comment: I have tested with a json file I found online: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/melqkiades/yelp/master/notebooks/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json and it give me 0 errors. Also in your code you have a json file, but your image is a csv file, are you selecting the correct file?

Comment: I will look into it, with your file ;)

Comment: @AbrahamSoto That's odd. I'm running it on Jupyter Notebook. Can it be because of the environment? Thank you.

Comment: @AbrahamSoto I followed what Grabiel M advised me and it worked. Now the problem seems to be how to make it work for 'Hotels' too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Your code is breaking in the business with index 21.

```
if 'RestaurantsPriceRange2' in data2[entry]['attributes']:
```

That statement checks if "restaurantsPriceRange2" is in the array data2[entry]['attributes'] but in the business 21 the ['attributes'] value is None, I think because the business has no attributes.

```
print data2[21]

{u'city': u'Cleveland', u'neighborhood': u'Central', u'name': u"Rally's Hamburgers", u'business_id': u'gJ5xSt6147gkcZ9Es0WxlA', u'longitude': -81.6663746, u'hours': None, u'state': u'OH', u'postal_code': u'44115', u'categories': u'Fast Food, Burgers, Restaurants', u'stars': 3.0, u'address': u'3040 Carnegie Ave', u'latitude': 41.4999894, u'review_count': 5, u'attributes': None, u'is_open': 1}
```

So you can deal with the error with an If, checking if data2[entry]['attributes'] is something instead of none.

```
if data2[entry]['attributes'] != None:
```

Testing I also found that if "Restaurants" in data2[entry]["categories"]: gives the same error in some business so, the entire code would look like this:

```
import json;

data2 = []
with open('yelp_academic_dataset_business.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data2.append(json.loads(line))
len(data2)

business_id = []
city = []
state = []
stars = []
review_count = []
categories = []
postal_code = []
latitude = []
longitude = []
pricerange = []
is_open = []
name = []

for entry in range(0, len(data2)):
    if data2[entry]["categories"] != None:
        if "Restaurants" in data2[entry]["categories"]:
            business_id.append(data2[entry]['business_id'])
            name.append(data2[entry]['name'])
            city.append(data2[entry]['city'])
            state.append(data2[entry]['state'])
            stars.append(data2[entry]['stars'])
            postal_code.append(data2[entry]['postal_code'])
            review_count.append(data2[entry]['review_count'])
            categories.append(data2[entry]['categories'])
            latitude.append(data2[entry]['latitude'])
            longitude.append(data2[entry]['longitude'])
            is_open.append(data2[entry]['is_open'])
            if data2[entry]['attributes'] != None:
                if 'RestaurantsPriceRange2' in data2[entry]['attributes']:
                     pricerange.append(data2[entry]['attributes']['RestaurantsPriceRange2'])
                else:
                    pricerange.append(0)

data2 = {'business_id ':business_id,'name':name,'city':city,'state':state,'stars':stars,'review_count':review_count,'categories':categories,'latitude':latitude,'longitude':longitude,'is_open':is_open,'pricerange':pricerange,'postal_code':postal_code}
```

Keep in mind that when you are reading json, you need to be aware of nulls, or empty arrays, so you always want to check if the value exists so your program do not crash.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very useful and it has taught me big lesson!

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are iterating on a None object.

Basically `data2[entry]['attributes']` is not a list, but a `None`

So when you do

```
if 'RestaurantsPriceRange2'in data2[entry]['attributes']:
```

you cannot check if the element is in the list because it is not a list.

So you have to check first if it is a list.
The correct line is

```
if data2[entry]['attributes'] and 
   'RestaurantsPriceRange2'in data2[entry]['attributes']:
```